# How to get value from select value in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1

i need to get the value from a select tag, but the problem is that i need to send the value to the route for example :

```
<select name="feeling">
<option value="0">Joyous</option>
<option value="1">Glad</option>
<option value="2">Ecstatic</option>
```

I neeed to send the value to a route like this:
retrieve_money/0/account

How can i get the value and send into another route
retrieve_money/{in this camp i need the value}/account

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You could accomplish this using JavaScript by making the following modifications

***In View***

```
<select onChange="newFunction(this)" name="feeling">
<option value="0">Joyous</option>
<option value="1">Glad</option>
<option value="2">Ecstatic</option>
```

***In Script***

```
function newFunction(newVal){    
    window.location.href = '/retrieve_money/'+newVal+'/account';
}
```

***In Routes***

```
Route::get('/retrieve_money/{selectVal}/account', ['uses' => 'DemoController@demoFunction');
```

Hope this would get you started.